# How to make an application only accessible to those with a college/university email

Tags: email, verification

I have no idea where to start in all honesty. If I make a phone app, for example, how would I go about only allowing people with a university (college) email address to sign up? Would it be as simple as verifying that the input is in fact an email address and then just sending a verification code to that email address?

Comment: I assume that you are talking about college students, not just faculty?  Are you planning on allowing them to continue using your application after they leave college?  If so, you'll also have to come up with a scheme for allowing them to use their college address to validate a personal non-edu e-mail address.

Comment: @ScottGartner Fair point, but no - once the user has left university there is no need for them to continue using the app (for the time being).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Send confirmation codes, activation links, or whatever only to .edu addresses -- and other specific, whitelisted addresses or domains as-needed for development, testing, administration, etc.